# Protected from attacks through Skype

Tags: security, skype, denial-of-service

I know that people can find your IP through Skype and try to DDOS it and take your Internet down for a couple of minutes or hours. What I would like to know is:

- How many people need to DDOS you at the same time to take your net down
- How can you be protected from those attacks and people finding your IP

Comment: Are you a well-know YouTube or Streamer? If not, don't worry about it.

Comment: A) Your IP Address isn't actually exposed by using Skype B) How many people need to particpate in a DDOS attack depends on any number of factors.

Comment: @tombull89 I might not be well known in the places you mentioned but I might be elsewhere. So let me worry about that.

Comment: @Ramhound It actually is. A few sites allow to other people to find your IP just by knowing your Skype username.

Answer (score 0):

Well for your first question, there’s no simple answer. we'd need to know your capacity, the proximity (in terms of bandwidth and accessibility, not physical distance per se) of the attackers, the tools/methodologies they use, and what mitigations are in place both on your end and on the isp tier. Many DOS tactics do not rely on filling up incoming bandwidth, but instead attack applications, or implementations of the IP stack.

As for your IP, No, I don't believe that skype does in fact share peer addresses at all, but if we were talking about a service that did, the only way to hide your address in any kind of point-to-point transmission is to use a proxy for the protocol in use.